# Calling .then on a dispatch in axios/react

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios, thunk

I have the following code:

```
   ....  
 then(() => {
 return Promise.all([
          dispatch(setAnimalCharacteristics(animalform))
        ])
          .then(() => {
            history.push("/animals);
          })
```

Is there a way to remove the Promise.all and just call the dispatch(setAnimalCharacteristics)?

I tried to run this:

```
 then(() => {
   return dispatch(setAnimalCharacteristics(animalform)).then(() => {
```

And I get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: you can't call `then` because dispatch doesn't return a promise out the box. you could use `async/await` instead?

Comment: oh i see... ok i'll loom for an example for that thanks

Comment: @RedBaron If it doesn't return a promise, using `await` won't help either

Comment: @Bergi actually that's not entirely true. what the OP wants doing is calling `history.push` after they have dispatched. so `async/await` will be fine. `then` wont as it requires a promise

Comment: @RedBaron `await` requires a promise as well if you want it to wait for something asynchronus. If you don't want to wait, you shouldn't use either. Just call `dispatch(…); history.push(…);`

Comment: ok fair point. `async/await` at least wont break then, unlike `.then` in this case ;) but yes best to use what you've suggested above. although there is a case that if this was wrapped in a `try/catch` then it would make sense to use `async/await` in case the dispatch `try` failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
await dispatch(setAnimalCharacteristics(animalform))

history.push("/animals);
```

the only part of your code I can't see is the function it is called in where you'll need to add they key word `async` so you can use `await`

but here is a guess:

```
const yourFunction async = () => {
   await dispatch(setAnimalCharacteristics(animalform))

   history.push("/animals);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to nest then() function if you want to navigate after dispatching the action. There are couple of ways you can resolve it.

1. Then can be chained like below.

```
.then(() => dispatch(setAnimalCharacteristics(animalform)))
.then(() => history.push("/animals);)
```

2. Wite the history.push inside of your setAnimalCharacteristics function at the end. We use this pattern the most to navigate after an API call is complete.

Hope this helps !

Comment: this will only work if the OP is returning a promise from dispatch otherwise `.then` wont work

Comment: thanks! yes unfortunately i'm not returning a promise so I can't use this solution

Comment: @RedBaron No, `then` callbacks can return normal values as well

Comment: @lost9123193 If you're not returning a promise, then why are you trying to `.then()`-chain something at all? Just write `.then(() => { dispatch(setAnimalCharacteristics(animalform)); history.push("/animals); })`

Comment: @Bergi have to call 1 more then to push it to /animals only after the calls within setAnimalCharacteristics are complete

Comment: @lost9123193 Either `setAnimalCharacteristics` completes synchronously, in which case this works, or it completes asynchronously, in which case you must return a promise instead of `undefined` (so that your original attempt would work as well).

Comment: Javascript's async nature will jump to the next statement history.push as setAnimalCharacteristics  is not awaited. So Awaiter might be needed for  setAnimalCharacteristics.